# How to add multiples of foreign key "ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle10g

```
create table coc (
WS_NO number(10,0) PRIMARY KEY,
last_name varchar2(30),
first_name varchar2(30),
middle_initial varchar2(1),
Email varchar2(2),
contact_no varchar2(11),
date_to_be_submitted date,
applicant_id number(10,0),
company_name VARCHAR2(50),
plant_location VARCHAR2(50),
sample_id number(10,0),
sample_name VARCHAR2(50),
parameters VARCHAR2(50),
CONSTRAINT APPLICANT_FK FOREIGN KEY (applicant_id, company_name, plant_location) REFERENCES APPLICANT (applicant_id, company_name, plant_location),
CONSTRAINT SAMPLE_FK FOREIGN KEY (sample_id, sample_name, parameters) REFERENCES SAMPLE (sample_id, sample_name, parameters));
```

Comment: I see you had a different error message, Gordon gave you the answer, then you CHANGED both the code and the question (which appears in the title only), with NO EXPLANATION and no credit given to Gordon. You should instead mark Gordon's answer "Correct" and ask a DIFFERENT question - while linking back to this one, explaining they are related but different. VERY UN-COOL!

Comment: sorry newbie here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error message is quite clear.  You have columns mentioned in a foreign key constraint, but they are not defined.  You need to define them if you want them to reference something else:

```
create table coc (
    WS_NO number(10,0) PRIMARY KEY,
    last_name varchar2(30),
    first_name varchar2(30),
    middle_initial varchar2(1),
    Email varchar2(2),
    contact_no varchar2(11),
    date_to_be_submitted date,
    applicant_id ??,
    company_name ??,
    plant_location ??,
    sample_id ??,
    sample_name ??,
    CONSTRAINT APPLICANT_FK FOREIGN KEY (applicant_id, company_name, plant_location) REFERENCES APPLICANT (applicant_id, company_name, plant_location),
    CONSTRAINT SAMPLE_FK FOREIGN KEY (sample_id, sample_name, parameters) REFERENCES SAMPLE (sample_id, sample_name, plant_location)
);
```

Remember:  The types need to be the same as in the original table.

Comment: AWWW OKAY THANKS!!

Answer (score 0):

The sets of columns (applicant_id, company_name, plant_location) and (sample_id, sample_name, parameters) must be set as unique or primary key in the referenced tables APPLICANT and SAMPLE. Check this by selection from ALL_CONS_COLUMNS filtering by table_name.